# In guest session, Google Chrome won't start and hibernation is missing in menu

Tags: 14.04, google-chrome, hibernate, guest-session

In guest session, hibernate missing in menu and Google Chrome won't start from dash.  I have enabled hibernation, as it works without problems. When I click on Chrome icon from Dash, nothing happens. However, Firefox works well. Any ideas?

Comment: The Chrome issue is claimed to have been fixed. https://launchpad.net/bugs/1298021 Is your system up to date?

Comment: I'm up to date, and I don't think the bug you gave link to is related with my problem.

Comment: I have the same issue with chrome and playonlinux. If you put on terminal google-chrome --no-sandbox it works. However, I do not know how to fix it.

Comment: It appears the maintainers updated the codebase, but not released a new update package. https://code.launchpad.net/~lightdm-team/lightdm/1.10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two solutions to Google Chrome problem:

1. Use Ubuntu 14.10, 15.10. Chrome now works in Guest Session.
2. Under 14.04 run Chrome from a terminal: Ctrl-shift-t to invoke terminal. `google-chrome --no-sandbox` launches Chrome.

FYI You can use the account 'guest prefs' to create a shortcut that launches that command under 14.04. Obviously that's unnecessary under newer versions, but, then again, there are some compelling reasons for some users to still be on the LTS version.

Fyi. The question about Chrome has been answered elsewhere.

Comment: Strange. It does not work in 15.04 nor in 15.10: when you run google-chrome from a guest account, it just says  `Check failed: NamespaceUtils::DenySetgroups()` and then does nothing.

Comment: @CPBL Odd. I've just set up 15.10 and under Guest account (via guest-prefs) Google Chrome works flawlessly.